# how to create a file in shell_exec command php in ubuntu return error (unable to open file)

Tags: php, linux

I want to create an empty file with the command `shell_exec` in PHP and use the `touch` command to create a file and open it, but the file was not created and it was not possible to write into the file.

```php
$newdate=date('Y-m-d');
echo $filepermission=__DIR__ . '/wp-scan'.$newdate.'.txt';
$filecreate='touch '.$filepermission;
$permissionfile='chmod -R 777 '.$filepermission;
shell_exec($filecreate);
$myfile = fopen(__DIR__ . '/wp-scan'.$newdate.'.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Comment: Please check your error log.

Comment: Why do you need to do it with `shell_exec`? PHP has its own functions to create a file and change permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PHP functions, you don't need to use `shell_exec`.

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d');
$filename = __DIR__ . '/wp-scan'.$newdate.'.txt';
file_put_contents($filename, "") or die("Unable to create file!");
fchmod($filename, 0777) or die("Unable to change permissions!");
$myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```